# Swap elements in array without creating new array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I was asked for a method to return the arr if element == 5 to be pushed to the end of the array and if its not 5 to be pushed to the beginning of the arr have to do this without creating new array 
could you please help me solve this one time with iterating .each 
and another without .each 
Using ruby

Ruby please

end

puts put_num5_last([5,3,5,2,5,1,4])

Comment: what ve attempted so far?

Comment: Can you please explain the requirement a little more? I don't understand. When are you supposed to add at the end of the array, and when are you supposed to add at the beginninng?

Comment: _"I was asked for a method […] could you please help me"_ – since you were asked for a solution, I suppose you already have tried something. Show your attempt(s) please, so we know what's missing and how to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`sort_by!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21) method of Array.

In ruby there is a naming convention that methods ending with `!` are either *inplace* or *destructive*, that is they modify the receiver.

`sort_by` will return a new array (sorted), `sort_by!` will sort the array inplace.

```rb
input = [6, 5, 3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 4]

output = input.sort_by! do |a, b|
  if a == 5
    1
  else
    -1
  end
end

p input     #=> [4, 2, 1, 6, 3, 5, 5, 5]
p output    #=> [4, 2, 1, 6, 3, 5, 5, 5]
p input.object_id   #=> 70191237292740
p output.object_id  #=> 70191237292740
p input.object_id == output.object_id #=> true
```

Comment: Note that the remaining elements have been shuffled. That's because `sort_by` isn't stable. The expected result is probably `[6, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5]`.

Comment: @Stefan might be, not sure from the Question what the order of the remaining items should be from the question.

Comment: Using a [ternary *if*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Ternary+if) statement here would shorten the code a lot. I'd also recommend using http://ruby-doc.org/ as reference source since it's maintained by the Ruby creators. https://apidock.com/ is third party.

Comment: Changed the link. I've written the code with multiline block and multiline if/else on purpose as the OP seems to be a beginner and this is not about short but readable code.

Answer (score 0):

You could fish the fives out of the array, and concatenate them to the end.

```
numbs = [5, 3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 4]
fives = numbs.select { |numb| numb == 5 }
numbs.delete(5)
numbs.concat(fives)

numbs #=> [3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

This is not the most efficient solution, since both `select` and `delete` iterate over the full array. But this is the most readable. More efficient, but less readable would be:

```
numbs = [5, 3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 4]

# reverse loop to prevent shifting of elements that are not yet iterated
numbs.each_index.reverse_each do |index|
  next unless numbs[index] == 5
  numbs << numbs.delete_at(index)
end

numbs #=> [3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

The above only loops once over the array, removing the value from the array and appending it to the end.

Comment: Not sure if `select` satisfies the _"without creating new array"_ restriction.

Comment: @Stefan It only creates a temporary array which holds all the fives. My assumption was that the result shouldn't be a new array.